# Using Plotly to Make Bar Graphs inside a pipe in R

Tags: r, graph, plotly

I'm new at R programming and I want to make interactive bar graph using plotly instead of basic graph bar.
This is the previous code that create basic graph bar.

```
all_trips_v2 %>% 
  mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()
            ,average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
  arrange(member_casual, weekday)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")`
```

And this is the one that I use plotly to create the graph, but I found out it doesn't work the same way as the ggplot.

```
all_trips_v2 %>% 
  mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>%  
  group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>%
  summarise(number_of_rides = n(), 
            average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>%
  arrange(member_casual, weekday) %>%

  plot_ly(all_trips_v2, x = ~weekday, y = ~number_of_rides, type = 'bar', name = 'member') %>%
  add_trace(y = n_distinct(all_trips_v2$member_casual), name = 'casual') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Average duration'), barmode = 'group')
```

Is that possible to use plotly inside a pipe? Or there are other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: you say `but I found out it doesn't work the same way as the ggplot.` but in fact, you have done it differently than how you did it for ggplot.  ggplot take a data argument; and  in your first code you manipulate a dataframe via a pipe and go on to use the pipe to enter ggplot substituting the data content in. The same can be said of plot_ly, but you broke the pattern by repeating the `all_trips_v2` name,  -- not trusting that it would be piped  in ?

Comment: I already knew repeating the 'all_trips_v2' is wrong and I didn't know the 'data' argument in plot_ly function is optional before I re-read the documentation. So, I deleted 'all_trips_v2' and it works. Thanks